# rasberry pi connection sensor DHT11

Tags: raspberry-pi

Could somebody tell me please if I connected everything in a right way? I try to connect DHT to my raspberry pi 2. If I try to read data I'm getting:

```
Data (0): 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0
```

I tried almost every port GPIO

I did everything as it is here:
http://docs.gadgetkeeper.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=7700673

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question - it would be much better suited to the [Raspberry Pi StackExchange site](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1):

It's a little hard to see but that doesn't look like a 10k or 4.7k resistor but like 1k (5 band, Brown, Black, Grey, Brown?).

Edit: As you used a 10 ohm resistor you shorted data to VCC which messes the data transmission up. The DHT11 is fine, you just need to use the proper transistor. You need a so called pull up resistor, which should be like stated around 4-10k.

Comment: It is a first time that I'm connecting such things ;) I used 10k resistor. bought this from here http://allegro.pl/rezystor-2w-10r-10ohm-10szt-i5108765948.html ? Could you please tell me if it is right?

Comment: These are 10 ohm resistor not 10k ohm (10.000 ohm). 10 ohm is pretty much a short to VCC.

Get a 10k resistor and it should work.

Comment: These should do: http://allegro.pl/x-tron-rezystor-0-25w-weglowy-10k-ohm-5-i5590587649.html

Comment: Thanks ;) but will my DHT11 still work or probably it is damaged that I used a wrong resistor

Comment: It should be absolutely fine. What you did right now is vomit the data line full with 1's because you have a practical short to VCC. With the 10k resistor that will not happen but keep the data line HIGH (logical 1) when there is no data coming in.